# "Error occurred when trying to create a controller" with no reason and happening randomly

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, umbraco7, asp.net-apicontroller, .net-4.7.2

I have a very weird thing happening randomly.

I have an api controller (`UmbracoAPiController` in fact) and it all works fine both on local and test site with dependency injection (Autofac 5.1.2).

However sometimes when I add a very simple code of line like

```
var somevariable = "some variable";
```

then it cannot recognise the controller any more as if the dependency injection stopped working:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyApiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Type 'MyDomain.Api.Controllers.MyApiController' does not have a default constructor",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
  }
}
```

It really happens randomly.

Then I need to delete the line compile and then add that line back again, compile and it sometimes starts working or sometimes I need to repeat deletion and re-addition more than once to make it working.

Also when I get it working locally then the same code sometimes fails on test site. And I need to do as the above and deploy again to test for it to start working again.

It is really frustrating as there is nothing to brake the code and it all happens randomly.

I don't know what it could be sensitive about. I know it's not much but it's literally what's happening.

I am using AutoFac 5.1.2 with .NET 4.7.2

Just to add all api controllers fail because of it, not only this one. So DI must be fussy about something on that project.

Comment: I don't have an answer but just wanted to add, that I ran into the same problem today. Locally everything works fine but when deployed to an Azure App Service, I get the error. It even throws the error, when I clone an existing, working Azure App Service. Do you have the problem in Azure aswell? Might be an issue with Azure right now.

Comment: No, I have a dedicated server on Windows. My issue is also random on the server - sometimes work sometimes not with the same code.

Comment: Anyone have an idea why this could be?

Comment: Currently the issue persists on our staging server while live and localhost is working correctly. We have replaced the staging files with the live ones and still it persists. Really perplexing. Any clue why one server is facing the issue, another (with exatly the same files) is not?